# Jquery to get the value of Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I'm using following html for dropdownlist,

```
   <select id="dd">
   <option>Select ReportType</option>
   <option value="1">Blocked Details</option>
   <option value="2">Supervisor Input</option>
   </select>
```

Following code for a button,

```
  <input type="button" name="Excel" value="ExportToExcel" onclick="javascript:DownloadExcel($('#dropdown').val());" />
```

Following is the Jquery function,

```
   function DownloadExcel(value)
{  
debugger;
if(value=="Blocked Details"){
value="1";
}
else if(value=="Supervisor Input"){
value="2";
}
    $.ajax({
    url:"@Url.Action("TravelReadyAdminDownload", "TravelReady")",
    datatype:"html",
    type:"post",
    data:{Id:value},
    error:function(){},
    success:function(data){
    window.location.href=data.url;}     
    });   
}
```

is it possible to get the dropdown values("1/2" instead of "Blocked Details/Supervisor Input").What is the javascript i need to use to get the value in that function?

Comment: `$("#dd option:selected").val() will do.

Answer (score 2):

*Selected dropdown value* can be fetched like

```
$('#dd').val();
```

or

```
$('#dd option:selected').val();
```

---

**EDIT:** Actually you're doing it right, following are your mistakes

1) wrong selector

```
$('#dropdown').val()// WRONG selector
```

it has to be

```
onclick="javascript:DownloadExcel($('#ddd').val());" //Correct
```

2) **`value`** parameter will hold only value *(1 or 2)* **not text** *(Blocked Details or Supervisor Input)*

Also following is the right way

```
if(value=="1"){
    //do something
}
else if(value=="2"){
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following
`$('#dropdown :selected').val()`

Comment: This does the same as $('#dropdown').val(), but slows down the selector unnecessarily. See http://api.jquery.com/val/